# QTableView, after a modification

Tags: python, pyqt

My program has a QTableView, which displays data from a sqlite database. As my program is going to be used to sort videos files, not too numerous, I modified the select method of the model, to load all the database in memory, instead of 255 entries (by default). It works well, but:

I also have a personal header, that I can click to sort the entries by modification date, name, and vote. Let's admit that I sort my data by modification data, without trying to modify anything: it works, everything is sorted.
But If a modify a cell, the name by example, here is what happens:

- the program loads 255 entries, sort them by date, then displays them
- it loads 255 other entries, sort them by date, then displays them
- etc

After a modification, if try again to sort the data by data, everything is normal.
But at each modification, the program loads 255 entries only. Basically, I'm missing a callback (the one that gets called after you update something).

I don't know if I have to fix the view or the model. Do you have an idea ?

In my app, I can use some functions of the view to fix it:

```
column_sorted = self.tableau.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorSection()
order = self.tableau.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorOrder()

if column_sorted is not None:
    self.tableau.sortByColumn(column_sorted, order)
else:
    pass
```

But I would prefer a more generic method.

Here is a piece of code which does a modification to my database:

```
def voter(self):

    self.bdd.close()
    liste.vote(self.current_video)
    self.bdd.open()
    self.modele.select()
```

But the problem appears with every function wich modifies the database. I would like to add that I use a QSortProxyFilter:

```
self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.modele)
```

Sorry if I'm not clear, but it's hard to describe this bug, and my app starts to be big (~3000 lines).

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a callback (the one that gets called after you update something).

Comment: Exactly, I would like to know its name, to re-implement it.

Comment: you should edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: could you post a simplified version of your code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I just edited the question.